# Ajax Javascript Get JSON value

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cordova

Hi I am developing an app in phonegap, where I am getting a particular value from server by connecting php file the value I need to pass is a string value 'pmnno'suppose whose value is '2' I need to get the value of '2' in column name 'personalnumber'.. So I am giving my code below

```
var jsonData;
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'http://xxxx.com/app/get_pday1_number.php', 
    data: { pmnno: '2' }, 
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (response) { 
jsonData = response;
        alert(jsonData);

    }
});
```

php code

```
<?php

// array for JSON response   
$response = array();    
    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';       

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();        

    // check for post data
    if (isset($_GET["pone"])) 

    {
        $pone = $_GET['pone'];           

        // get a product from products table
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM pdaynew WHERE pone = $pone");

        if (!empty($result)) {
            // check for empty result
            if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                $product = array();
                $product["pid"] = $result["pid"];                    
                $product["pone"] = $result["pone"];                    
                $product["personaldayone"] = $result["personaldayone"];
                $product["created_at"] = $result["created_at"];
                $product["updated_at"] = $result["updated_at"];                   

                // success
                $response["success"] = 1;         
                // user node
                $response["product"] = array();         
                array_push($response["product"], $product);         
                // echoing JSON response
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // no product found
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "No product found";

                // echo no users JSON
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // required field is missing
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

I am getting a success mesage that means connection is succesful but ineed the value of '2' in column 'personalnumber' for that where I need to add that code..If anyone knows pls help me...

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking, specifically what is the "column" you're talking about. Perhaps add the relevant HTML and an example of the desired outcome?

Comment: plz show the code of get_pday1_number.php

Comment: that means in my table where this php is connecting there is 4 columns are there first is number where 1-10 is there then description for that each numbers that is next column... so if value is 9 i need to get the description for 9 in the next column

Comment: @proyank please check I gave the php code

Comment: @Jocheved where are you getting "pmnno" value in get_pday1_number.php

Comment: @Jocheved i think you need to change in your ajax call like this "data: { pone: '2' }, "

Comment: sorry... I gave 'pone' instead of 'pmnno' ... but I am getting every columns value.. I need onluy personaldayone value

Comment: Sorry for being offtopic, but you're dropping a `GET` param into your query without any sanitation. That's calling for SQL injection.

Comment: @Jocheved what are the fields in you tables?

Comment: @Priyank pid, pone, personaldayone, created_ at, updated_at

Comment: @Jocheved then i think you need to change your query like "SELECT personaldayone FROM pdaynew WHERE pone = $pone"

Comment: Thanks Priyank.. without changing the php can u suggeest anyother option in javascript

Comment: @Jocheved your problem is not related to javascript.only you need to change your query,then everything should work.please see me answer below

Comment: ThaNKS Priyank... let me check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using * use personaldayone:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT personaldayone FROM pdaynew WHERE pone = $pone");
```

Comment: @Jocheved please upvote & accept.if my answer is useful for you.

Comment: It is working.. but {"success = 1,"product":[{" pone":null,"personaldayone":" Here I am getting the result"}]}... but I dont want these brackets and success and pone... only personaldayone value is needed